# Return value on stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a problem, when I execute this stored procedure:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TBL_M 
               WHERE TYPE_M = 'reservation' 
                 AND NUM_DESK = @NUMBER_DESK 
                 AND ID_TIME = @ID_TIME)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TBL_M 
    VALUES ('reservation', @NUMBER_DESK, @NUM_USER, @ID_TIME)
END
```

Everything works correctly, the only problem is that I want to know when the insert is executed the insert and when not.

In C# I use the following method `ExecuteNonQuery()`

But it always returns `-1`, how can you identify the insert and when it doesn't insert.

Comment: I'm baffled.  You are comparing a value to an `id` column with `@id`, but `@id` is not part of the `insert`.  You should always list the columns in an `insert`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I edited the SP and it is this, the previous one I tried to use as an example, but this is the one I am using

Comment: What do you mean by "returns -1"? As in the return code? If so `-1` means that the SP errored in some way. By Default the Return code `1` means success and **anything else** means failure. If it is failing, then an error message will also have been returned and you're likely surpressing it in your application code.

Comment: @Larnu return -1 in my C # app, using method ExecuteNonQuery() but in sql it works correct, if the record does not exist it does the insert, and if the record already exists it does not insert, I just want to know how to identify those who did not insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable

```
Declare @ROWCOUNT INT = 0
```

Assign the variable

```
Select @ROWCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Just after the insert (inside begin-end) either `return` or `select` (then you have to to use `ExecuteQuery` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`), or have an output parameter, to get the value of `@ROWCOUNT`.

@MickyD ' s suggestion:

The SQL variable [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) hold the number of rows affected by the last statement, in this case just after executing `Insert`. If any other operation is performed, that value will be not the same any more, hence assign that to a locally defined variable and pass back to the caller.

Comment: While you *can* use `return` to pass back the rows affected, you shouldn't because the conventional use of the return parameter is to return a code which tells you whether the SP succeeded or not, and the return code of `0` conventionally means success whereas any other value means failure (which is the reverse of what will happen using the row count).